# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'gcobani' to data type int.'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am running an exception, the conversion seem to fail when i try to create new user to the database. This hits on my Repository on this method below, meanwhile on my store procedure it returns an integer; The question would then be, how could I solve this issue? Please advice and help me to fix this better.

[image]

C# code:

```
public string GetUserName_By_UserID(string UserId)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ToString())) 
    {
        var para = new DynamicParameters();
        para.Add("@UserId", UserId);

        return con.Query<string>("Usp_UserNamebyUserID", para, null, true, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_UserNamebyUserID]  
    @UserId varchar(200)  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT UserName 
    FROM Users 
    WHERE Id = @UserId  
END
```

NB: my UserId I checked now on my table name "Users" I defined it as an Int, maybe this is the reason.

Comment: What is the param `@UserId` in the sproc, is it an `int`? You are passing a string to it, is that string `gcobani`? Can you debug, or run profiler to check?

Comment: @UserId on my store procedure varchar(200) character string. Yes gcobani is a string. Am i doing mix mode here?

Comment: Please, mention your SP "Usp_UserNamebyUserID" at here.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. An `int` was expected, not a string. You didn't post the contents of `Usp_UserNamebyUserID` so it's impossible to help. Perhaps `UserId` should be an `int`. Or some query in the stored procedure tries to match int and text fields with incompatible contents.

Comment: @eNtsa2019Mkontwana so post the stored procedure code. This has nothing to do with C#. It's impossible to help without the *relevant* code

Comment: SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE proc [dbo].[Usp_UserNamebyUserID]  
@UserId varchar(200)  
as  
begin  
  
select UserName FROM Users where Id =@UserId  
  
end
GO

Comment: Here you mention id with string in where clause. Please, pass int as parameter or search with user name.

Comment: @eNtsa2019Mkontwana update the *question* and add the code there. That stored procedure doesn't contain any `gcobani` table or parameter. Are you sure you aren't looking at the wrong code? The *only* way this stored procedure could through is for `Users` to be a view that uses `gcobani` somewhere

Comment: Still the question remains, is `Id` in your table an `int`?

Comment: Post the *actual* exception text including any inner exceptions and the stack trace. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. This will show where the actual exception occurred and which calls lead to it. Post the *entire* string as is, not just the message or stack trace. You can also get all the details from Visual Studio's exception dialog box by [clicking on `Copy Exception Details to Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saraford/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276)

Comment: Looks to me like you are passing a username to a userid column. You need to sort what you are passing to the sproc, and ensure you are using the correct column to query on.

Comment: Or is `gcobani` the content of the `UserID` parameter? In that case the actual error is farther up in the C# code. For starters, change both the stored procedure's **and** GetUserName_By_UserID's parameters to `int`. In whatever code calls `GetUserName_By_UserID`, ensure you parse any input into an `int` with `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`. Don't ignore errors.

Comment: @eNtsa2019Mkontwana Beyond that, you'll have to add input validation at the UI, MVC action or Web API level to ensure invalid data can't be passed to your code in the first place. This could have been a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with below SP:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Usp_UserNamebyUserID]
@UserId int
as
begin
select UserName FROM Users where Id =@UserId
end
```

You have to change your c# code like:

```
public string GetUserName_By_UserID(Int UserId)
        {
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyString"].ToString())) {

                var para = new DynamicParameters();
                para.Add("@UserId", UserId);
                return con.Query<string>("Usp_UserNamebyUserID", para, null, true, 0, CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        }
```

Comment: That won't necessarily work if what is being passed from the C# code is not a user id. I think there is a mix of logic here.

Comment: This *will* work if `gcobani` is actually the *content* of the parameter, not the name of a field

Comment: Because your method name said that get user name from user_id.

Comment: That change in itself may still not fix it, it will just move the error to the layer above the repo if it is passing a string to this method. The logic is wrong, fundamentally.

Comment: @Leonidas199x the OP *has* to make those changes. By doing so, the code will be *forced* to parse the input and handle errors. It won't just move the error one level up, C# doesn't allow implicit conversions between string and int. A full answer would require adding input validation to the UI, any web forms or API endpoints etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It will cause a build error, until OP goes through and changes everything. Hence why I am saying this answer doesn't really tell OP what the problem is. The issue is, they have mixed username and id, and that is what needs sorting. We don't even know if it should be searching by Username or Id at this point, just presume that OP means Id